# mosaic rasters with gdal_merge.py

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge, subprocess

I want to mosaic 2 rasters "rasa" and "rasb" using gdal_merge.py . While running the code, it produces an error " No input files selected". Can somebody help me to find the error in the code?

```
    import subprocess
    filea = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasa.tif'
    fileb = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasb.tif'
    output = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/output.tif'
    subprocess.call(['gdal_merge','-o',output,filea,fileb],shell=True)
```

when i run the above code, the output i am getting is:
[image]

Comment: have you tried directly from the command line? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am trying it in eclipse pydev. OS: Windows 7, python v 3.4

Comment: so why don't you import gdal_merge instead of calling it from the command line? try to find a way to print or log the statement you are sending to the command line. I guess something is going wrong there. Maybe you can first try to switch subprocess to os.system(). and do it simple os.system('gdal_merge -o ' + output + ' ' + filea + ' ' + fileb). Maybe the spaces are missing in the subprocess command.

Comment: Try just running it from the `C:\Users\claudio\workspace\test\test1` directory, without the full paths.

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts which makes it hard for you to communicate with potential answerers.  Please follow these instructions to merge your two accounts ASAP: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing a list to subprocess then specifying `shell=True` (which expects a string as input) so it is only taking the first item in the list, which is `gdal_merge`, and running this. Just running `gdal_merge.py` gives the same error.

The same code but without `shell=True` should work:

```
import subprocess
filea = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasa.tif'
fileb = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasb.tif'
output = 'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/output.tif'
subprocess.call(['gdal_merge', '-o' , output, filea, fileb])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the files at the paths `filea` and `fileb` exist?

Try:

```
filea = r'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasa.tif'
fileb = r'C:/Users/claudio/workspace/test/test1/rasb.tif'
```